# HQL Multi Table Select - Outer Join?

Tags: hibernate, grails, hql, outer-join

I'm trying to perform an `HQL` query that combines data from two objects: `Person`, and `PersonRoleAssociation`.

I'm running `Hibernate` 4.3.10, and `Grails` 3.0.10.

My current query looks something like this:

```
SELECT person 
  FROM Person person, 
       PersonRoleAssociation personRoleAssoc
 WHERE personRoleAssoc.person = person
```

From my understanding this is equivalent to a standard `SQL` inner left join. This works for most cases, but I also need to query for all `Persons` that lack a `PersonRoleAssociation`, and because the above query is a left join I run into issues.

In standard `SQL` I would simply use a left outer join, however I can't find any equivalent for `HQL`.

How would I perform the equivalent of a outer join in `HQL` without changing the structure of my objects?

Comment: do you have PersonRoleAssociation  mapped as OneToMany relation in the Person entity?

Comment: @MaciejKowalski No, I've heard that having OneToMany relationships in Grails can be quite slow, so I've tried to avoid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot add an OneToMany on the Person side and use the standard left outer join then i think you should go for a right join. Something like:

```
SELECT p 
  FROM PersonRoleAssociation personRoleAssoc
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN personRoleAssoc.person p       
 WHERE /* other criteria */
```

Comment: No problem. Glad i could help